# Intersection of sorted lists

Tags: python, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

I don't like this function. Looks too imperative.

It takes two sorted lists and returns a sorted intersection of the two lists. There is an implicit assumption that there are no duplicate elements in either list.

Please don't suggest converting (even one of) the arguments to `set`, or using some sort of library function. This is a single-pass O(n+m) time, O(1) auxiliary space algorithm, and I want to keep it that way.

```
def sorted_lists_intersection(lst1, lst2):

  i1 = 0
  i2 = 0
  len1 = len(lst1)
  len2 = len(lst2)

  intersection = []

  while i1 < len1 and i2 < len2:

    while lst1[i1] < lst2[i2]:
      i1 += 1
      if i1 == len1:
        return intersection

    while lst2[i2] < lst1[i1]:
      i2 += 1
      if i2 == len2:
        return intersection

    if lst1[i1] == lst2[i2]:
      intersection.append(lst1[i1])
      i1 += 1
      i2 += 1

  return intersection
```

Comment: You can still use a `set` or `dict` and maintain runtime of O(n+m). So what's the reason behind not using them? Is it to not use extra space?

Comment: Basically yes. There may be other implications of using a `set` or `dict`, such as maintaining sortedness (although this one could be solved easily by something like `filter(x, set(y))`). Besides, I wanted to see a more elegant way to write this specific function (without sets), since I found the original code too much like C/C++/etc.; too unpythonic.

Answer (score 15):

While you don't want alternative solutions, you should take a look at the data in your specific usecase. As an example, for some randomly generated input (both lists of length ~600) on my machine (Python 3.6.9, GCC 8.3.0), your function takes

```
In [18]: %timeit sorted_lists_intersection(a, b)
179 µs ± 1.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The function defined in the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/233453/98493) by [@alexyorke](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/8149/alexyorke), while more readable IMO, takes a bit longer:

```
In [16]: %timeit list(intersect(a, b))
249 µs ± 4.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In contrast, this highly readable and short implementation using `set` and `sorted`, that completely disregards the fact that the lists are already sorted (which means that it also works with unsorted lists):

```
def intersect_set(a, b):
    return sorted(set(a) & set(b))
```

is about twice as fast:

```
In [29]: %timeit intersect_set(a, b)
77 µs ± 1.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Of course, in order to properly compare them, here are more data points:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

ns = np.logspace(1, 6, dtype=int)
inputs = [[sorted(set(np.random.randint(1, n * 10, n))) for _ in range(2)] for n in ns]
```

The `set` based function wins in all of these test cases:

[image]

It looks like for lists with lengths of the order of more than 10M your function might eventually win, due to the \$\mathcal{O}(n\log n)\$ nature of `sorted`.

I think the greater speed (for a wide range of list sizes), coupled with the higher readability, maintainability and versatility makes this approach superior. Of course it requires objects to be hashable, not just orderable.

Whether or not this data is similar enough to yours, or whether or not you get the same timings, performing them to see which one is the best solution in your particular usecase is my actual recommendation.

Comment: Interesting; I ran your inputs with `timeit.Timer.autorange` and got [these results](https://i.imgur.com/IURmjaA.png). Also, keep in mind that my method as well as alexyorke's is implemented in pure Python, whereas `set` and `sorted` are implemented in C, that's why it's so fast.

Comment: @kyrill: Interesting results. Which Python version did you use? The one I used is 3.6.9.

Comment: `3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: @kyrill: Using functions implemented in C instead of doing everything in Python *is* the best practice because removes the interpreter overhead; `more-itertools` recipes do this for all the functions inside. Why are you trying to avoid best practice?

Comment: @Voile I think you got me wrong. I don't want to avoid C; I want to avoid creating a `set` if I already have a `list` which may be large. Furthermore, using my original approach as opposed to a set-based one, I can consume elements on the fly, so I can even process infinite iterables (assuming they are sorted).

Comment: @kyrill Then you *definitely* should modify your function to take iterables and `yield` values instead while utilizing the `itertools` functions; they're mostly written in C and this is the kind of situation they're used for. It's much cleaner and prevents all the clumsy store-keeping revolving around lists.

Comment: I said I *can* consume elements on the fly if I wanted to, not that I do. This is easy to see and I don't feel the need to modify my original function to make it any more obvious. Anyhow, which `itertools` functions are you talking about?

Answer (score 9):

The code seems to be too complicated. There are a few ways it can be optimized:

```
if i1 == len1:
        return intersection
```

and

```
if i2 == len2:
        return intersection
```

return statements can be expressed as `yield` so that the return for the entire array is not required; it returns constantly. However, this condition needs to be there otherwise it won't work; it can be refactored into incrementing both pointers step-wise instead, which eliminates boundary checks and `intersection.append(lst1[i1])`.

With these rules applied, the following is the refactored version:

```
def intersect(a, b):
  i = 0
  j = 0
  while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] > b[j]:
      j += 1
    elif a[i] < b[j]:
      i += 1
    else:
      yield a[i]
      j += 1
      i += 1
```

Depending on readability, it can be expressed more tersely as:

```
def intersect(a, b):
  i = 0
  j = 0
  while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] == b[j]:
      yield a[i]
    i, j = i + (a[i] <= b[j]), j + (a[i] >= b[j])
```

This works because boolean operators return `0` if false and `1` if true. Since the failure conditions will add `0`, it won't affect the result. The variables have to be assigned together on one line as it has to use `i` and `j` copies for array indexing.

Comment: @kyrill thank you for your suggestions; I have updated my answer

Comment: Note my first suggestion

Comment: And what do you mean by "return statements can be expressed as yield" ?

Comment: @kyrill The `yield` operator "returns" a value when called; the function can then be wrapped in a `list()` to get the same "behavior| as returning/appending a list in a loop

Comment: I must say I find your new `while` condition quite confusing...

Comment: @kyrill I removed it a few minutes ago; it was not working for some inputs

Comment: While the terse function works I don't think it's worth the extra programmer overhead in understanding it to save 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 8):

If you treated your 2 inputs as iterables instead of simply lists, you could think in terms of `for` loops with direct access to elements instead of using `__getitem__` all around. The second advantage being, obviously, that you can call the function using any iterable instead of only lists; so data that is in a file, for instance, can be processed with, *e.g.*:

```
target = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
with open(my_file) as f:
    common = sorted_lists_intersection(target, map(int, f))
```

without having to store the whole file in memory at once.

If you also make sure to turn your function into a generator, you can directly iterate over the results without having to store all of them at once in memory either; and you can still call `list` on the function if you truly need a list.

I propose the following implementation that have the same precondition than yours: the inputs must be sorted and should not contain duplicates:

```
from contextlib import suppress


def intersect_sorted_iterables(iterable1, iterable2):
    iterator = iter(iterable2)

    with suppress(StopIteration):
        other = next(iterator)

        for element in iterable1:
            if element > other:
                other = next(x for x in iterator if x >= element)
            if element == other:
                yield element
```

This version will take advantage of `next` raising `StopIteration` to exit the loop when any of the iterable is exhausted, making it par with your `len` checks.

Comment: I played with the idea of using iterators with `next` but found it less elegant than the original code. Your idea is interesting as well, but TBH the code is a bit convoluted, especially the `for` loop with conditional `continue` and unconditional `break`. I think it would be neater if you did something like `other = next(x for x in iterator if x >= element)`.

Comment: @kyrill Yes, that's a neat rewrite of the inner for loop that get rid of the "must iterate over the whole first iterator" constraint.

Comment: You can exit the first loop with a return statement in an `else` block of the second loop, which triggers when the second iterator is exhausted.

Comment: @moooeeep Updated the code with the suggestion from kyrill, so this is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 6):

My own contribution.

I took inspiration from 409_Conflict and made a lazy generator which takes sorted iterables.

I further generalized it to accept an arbitrary (but non-zero) number of iterables and return their mutual intersection.

The time complexity of this algorithm is \$O(n^2*\min\{\text{len}(it) \ \vert\  it \in \texttt{iterables}\})\$ where \$n = \text{len}(\texttt{iterables})\$. Using some smart datastructure such as Fibonacci heap, the asymptotic complexity could be improved at the cost of actual performance (and also readability and such).

```
import contextlib

def all_equal(items):
  """
  Returns `False` if and only if there is an element e2 in `items[1:]`,
  such that `items[0] == e2` is false.
  """
  items_it = iter(items)
  try:
    first_item = next(items_it)
  except StopIteration:
    return True

  return all(first_item == next_item for next_item in items_it)


def sorted_iterables_intersection(*iterables):

  iterators = [iter(iterable) for iterable in iterables]

  with contextlib.suppress(StopIteration):
    while True:
      elems = [next(it) for it in iterators]

      while not all_equal(elems):
        # Find the iterator with the lowest value and advance it.
        min_idx = min(range(len(iterables)), key=elems.__getitem__)
        min_it = iterators[min_idx]
        elems[min_idx] = next(min_it)

      yield elems[0]
​
```

Comment: Lastly, allowing for 0 iterables (if desired) is trivial by changing the `while True:` into `while iterators:`.

Comment: Regarding the `all_equal`: there's indeed no need for `zip`; I removed it and also replaced `try` with `contextlib.suppress`. As per allowing zero iterables: `while iterators` is the exact thing that came to my mind, and I swiftly dismissed the idea because there's really no need to keep repeatedly checking whether there are any iterators; you only need to check once. And adding a check before the while loop just didn't seem worth it ‒ why would you call the function with no arguments? Anyways, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The definition of `all_euqal()` is missing.

Comment: @kyrill Yes, also one can wonder where iterators is beeing modified in the first place. So I agree with your points, hence the "if desired".

Answer (score 6):

## using iterators

This is basically the same as your solution, but uses iterators instead of explicit indexing.  I find it easy to understand.

```
def sorted_list_intersection(list1, list2):
    iter1 = iter(list1)
    iter2 = iter(list2)

    intersection = []

    try:
        item1 = next(iter1)
        item2 = next(iter2)

        while True:
            if item1 == item2:
                intersection.append(item1)
                item1 = next(iter1)
                item2 = next(iter2)

            elif item1 < item2:
                item1 = next(iter1)

            else:
                item2 = next(iter2)

    except StopIteration:
        return intersection
```

Comment: I was going to post something very similar, but instead of the `intersection` intermediate list, and appending to it, `yield` each match

Comment: I'd suggest incorporating the `yield` as mentioned above. It would make sense to make your function a generator, since you're already using iterators (and hence possibly accepting generators as arguments).

Comment: I agree `yield item1` may be better than `intersection.append(item1)`, depending on the use case,  I was just mirroring what the OP code did.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly don't want to convert to sets, perhaps use the underlying idea that they implement. Note that `get_hash` is pretty arbitrary and definitely could be improved. [Here's a resource on improving the hashing and choice of `hash_map` size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

```
def get_hash(thing, hash_map):
    hashed = ((hash(thing) * 140683) ^ 9011) % len(hash_map)
    incr_amount = 1
    while hash_map[hashed] is not None and hash_map[hashed] != thing:
        hashed += incr_amount ** 2
        incr_amount += 1
        if hashed >= len(hash_map):
            hashed = hashed % len(hash_map)
    return hashed

def sorted_lists_intersection(a, b):
    hash_map = [None for _ in range(len(a) * 7 + 3)]

    for x in a:
        hash_map[get_hash(x, hash_map)] = x

    return filter(lambda x: x == hash_map[get_hash(x, hash_map)], b)
```

**Edit based on comments:**

Here is a O(m*n) [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) answer

```
def intersection_sorted_list(a, b):
    return filter(lambda x: x in a, b)
```

Now, if the lists are sorted we can speed this up a bit by shrinking the range we check against after each successive match. I believe this makes it O(m+n) time.

```
def intersection_sorted_list(a, b):
    start_indx = 0
    for x in b:
        for i in range(start_indx, len(a)):
            if a[i] == x:
                yield a[i]
            if a[i] >= x:
                start_indx = i + 1
                break
```

Comment: Pardon my French, but this is awful. Firstly, Python has a built-in `hash` function; secondly, Python has a built-in `dict` class which is a "hash map" and thirdly, what you try to accomplish using a hash map, can be accomplished using a `set`. Your answer can be summed up in one line: `return filter(lambda x: x in set(a), b)`. Which I explicitly stated I am not interested in.

Comment: @kyrill, the inbuilt function is not directly applicable for hashmaps, you need to find the modulo of it and perform probing at the very least. "what you try to accomplish using a hash map, can be accomplished using a set" I explicitly stated that was the purpose of my answer. You haven't stated what you are interested in, only "I don't like this function. Looks too imperative.". This a less imperative function. I don't understand what you are looking for since you are explicitly avoiding the best solution to your problem. I thought you were trying to avoid under the hood bloat of `set`.

Comment: @kyrill the answer you contributed is essentially a more abstract and less efficient implementation (due to doing O(n) lookups instead of hashes) of the above.

Comment: What I was interested in, is to avoid creating a `set` if I already have a (possibly huge) `list`. I have no comment on your second comment...

Comment: @kyrill This answer does not create a set, it creates a list of the same space complexity, which you can modify to be O(n) or O(m). Are you looking for an in-place algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm ?

Comment: Yes Budd, you understood that correctly. I am indeed looking for an in-place algorithm.

Comment: Can you find the mistake in your new version? Hint: the results it produces are correct (at least I think so; I haven't checked).

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. I quite like your "sorted list variant" - can't decide whether adding a break after the yield would be an improvement.

Comment: @kyrill results might not be intended if the values in a and b are non-unique, I'm not sure if you want unique values in the output.

Comment: @greybeard thanks, the second if condition is inclusive of the first and thus covers that ;)

Comment: It has nothing to do with duplicates. As I said, the results it produces are correct, and besides, I have stated that the inputs contain no duplicate values. Your new version simply doesn't work quite correctly – namely the "range shrinking" part.

Comment: @kyrill if you are aware of an error please point it out

Comment: You don't update `start_indx` if you skip over an element. Eg. `x` is 1 and `a` starts with [0, 2]; then you would advance `a[i]` from 0 to 2 without saving it, and break the loop because 2 > 1 (again without saving `i`). Then you would consume the next element from `b` and start comparing it again from the beginning of `a` (from 0), but you should start from the last consumed element of `a` (from 2).

Comment: I misremembered revisions up to 3.